# Bluej - Add random number, and name to arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I am trying to add a random number to an arraylist, along with a name. But I'm unsure how to make the arraylist understand that the random number is with the name I assign it to?

```
public class Myclass
{
// instance variables 
public Random f;
public String itemname;
public ArrayList <Integer> myList;

/**
 * Constructor for objects for class 
 */
public Myclass()
{
    f = new Random();
    thename = "name"; 
    myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public String setName(String name)
{
    name = itemname;
}

public int setnumber()
{
    number = (f.nextInt(10));
    Integer.toString(number);
    return number;
 }

public void addtoList()
{   
    item = number + itemname;
    flowerArray.add(item);
}
```

Comment: The thing you are trying to do makes no sense - it's a list of numbers, so it stores numbers, full stop. Perhaps you want a list of numbers and a separate list of names? Or a list of objects where each object has a number and a name (you'll need a new class for this one)? Or a HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong ,, as far i understand, you want to add a number and it's name together. in this case I think [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is your best option.. and if you have to use ArrayList, then store Object in the list. create a class which has both name and the value and in the List store the objects of that class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is :
1) Arraylist has been declared to hold integers. So it can hold nothing other than integers.

Solution : To hold integer and any other datatype. Please create a custom datatype, that can hold all the data you need.

2) Arraylist syntax is incorrect. (myList.add(~//add))

3) There are no dynamic variables in Java, so you have to declare the names of variables in source code.(This statement is partially correct as using ASM or BCEL, we can declare at bytecode level as well.)